# Storing anonymous user information in a cookie

Tags: cookies

I want to store the zip code of a user, if they use it for a proximity search in a cookie. However, I don't know where or how to start to implement this.

How do I store anonymous user information on a cookie?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Drupal 7, there are two functions to store data in a cookie: [user_cookie_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_cookie_save/7), and [user_cookie_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_cookie_delete/7). Despite the function names, the functions work also for anonymous users, since they don't get information from the `$user` object or any information that is related to the user ID.

[comment_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_form_submit/7) uses `user_cookie_save()` in the following code lines:

```
if (user_is_anonymous()) {
  user_cookie_save(array_intersect_key($form_state['values'], array_flip(array('name', 'mail', 'homepage'))));
}
```

If you are using a version of Drupal that doesn't define that functions, you can implement similar functions in a module you use.

```
function mymodule_cookie_save(array $values) {
  foreach ($values as $field => $value) {
    // Set cookie for 365 days.
    setrawcookie('Drupal.visitor.' . $field, rawurlencode($value), REQUEST_TIME + 31536000, '/');
  }
}

function mymodule_cookie_delete($cookie_name) {
  setrawcookie('Drupal.visitor.' . $cookie_name, '', REQUEST_TIME - 3600, '/');
}
```

Keep in mind that [setrawcookie()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.setrawcookie.php) is only available in PHP 5. If you are developing a module that could be used with PHP 4, then you should use [setcookie()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), and the code of the functions should be accordingly changed: the parameter needs to be declared as `$values` (not `array $values`), and the call to [rawurlencode()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) needs to be removed as the cookies are already URL encoded from `setcookie()`.

Comment: If you are developing code for Drupal 6, creating such functions would make your code compatible with Drupal 7; when porting the code to Drupal 7 you would just need to change the calls to `mymodule_cookie_save()` with `user_cookie_save()`. You could also use `user_cookie_save()` and `user_cookie_delete()` for your functions, if you first check those functions are not already defined, which would happen if another module defines them for Drupal 6.

Answer (score 3):

Setting cookies in Drupal is not different from how you would do it with any other PHP site:

[`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) is the function that PHP provides for this. There is also the `$_COOKIE` super global variable to use.

Code example:

```
$cookieval = 'my cookie value';
if ($_COOKIE['my_cookie_key'] != $cookie_val) {
 setcookie('my_cookie_key', $cookie_val);
}
```

Comment: The only example of this I can find is in the flag module which records anonymous users flags in client cookies. Perhaps it's the object oriented PHP, but the code is a little intimidating for me. I'll look at it again since from your suggesting its the write direction.

Comment: @Adam, I've added a code example of how you could set a cookie value (and how to get it) it is really not that hard.

Comment: I'll use $_COOKIE['location'] value for the default value of an exposed Views form for a proximity search. On submit I'll just check to see if the $_COOKIE['location'] value does not equal the $form_state value in which case I'll use the setcookie() function as you described above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Drupal installed in subfolder so that your site root URL has the form www.mydomain.com/mysite, you should probably use base_path() instead of '/' when setting the cookie.

Functions in kiamlaluno's answer would then be:

```
function mymodule_cookie_save(array $values) {
  foreach ($values as $field => $value) {
  // Set cookie for 365 days.
  setrawcookie('Drupal.visitor.' . $field, rawurlencode($value), REQUEST_TIME + 31536000, base_path());
  }
}

function mymodule_cookie_delete($cookie_name) {
  setrawcookie('Drupal.visitor.' . $cookie_name, '', REQUEST_TIME - 3600, base_path());
}
```