# Cookies for a webform using page breaks

Tags: webforms, cookies

I'm using the Webform module in a Drupal 6 installation. This webform is appearing in an iFrame, and can be found on every page. The website that contains the iframe is static, the Drupal installation with the Webform module is the only thing being loaded in the iframe. This webform is a quiz with 20 questions. The rest of the site is kind of like a handbook, and I want my users to be able to use the static handbook website as a guide while taking the quiz. Each quiz question is on its own page; I am using webform's pagebreaks to split each question up.

Is there a way to set a cookie that takes the user back to the question they left off at, should they choose to leave the form and return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some well written answers on using cookies in Drupal [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4419/storing-anonymous-user-information-in-a-cookie).

Comment: This answer is just a link to another question asked on this very site. To be an answer, you would write a summary in your own answer.

Comment: OK I will, I just thought those answers did a good job and I had nothing else I wanted to add for this question.